# Whats the right way to profile slow magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, slowbackend

I'm helping a friend to improve performance on their pretty mid-small sized magento store.

First thing I was looking is the Magento Profiler, from what I can see there is those methods that takes lots of time(6-7 seconds!)

```
layout/db_update: cms_menu  6.5310  1   0   0
layout/db_update: cms_page  6.5292  1   0   0
layout/db_update: STORE_default 6.5274  1   0   0
layout/db_update: THEME_frontend_agent_default  6.5256  1   0   0
layout/db_update: cms_index_index   6.5236  1   0   0
layout/db_update:   6.5217  1   0   0
layout/db_update: customer_logged_out
```

Any ideas how to go deeper and understand what's the bottleneck? I guess its some slow mysql queries.

I'm looking for tools/tips to help me to dig into it and get extra info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The profiler acts like a tree, so when you read that CMS_Page takes 6 seconds, you need to look deeper down the list to find out which sub-elements slow down the page that much (you should look for about 0.3s on CMS pages).

Aoe made an extension that makes the Profiler much more "User Friendly", but it's a matter of preference. Here is the link if you want to give it a try: https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Profiler

Then it's case-per-case. Most of the time, your bottleneck will come from modules or bad templating and unless you're in the milliseconds, it will be pretty obvious. A good way to have a point of comparison is to create a clean installation (on the same Magento version) and compare the times for each type of page; CMS, Category, Product, Homepage, Checkout being the critical ones.

Comment: Hi, thanks! will give aoe_profiler a chance.
I looked for the "first" event that took alot of time, and it's some template file: (homepage.phtml)

Will go over the code and will try to see if i see some bad code :)

Comment: Bad code in templates like `homepage.phtml` is a safe bet :D Watch out for products loaded in a loop

Comment: @fschmengler - yup! thats what I catched
https://gist.github.com/mp3il/30d4e33ab04a57e1d650

Im debugging it, but if you can point me (its my first time working with magento, though I have experience with php).

My guess is the $simple_product_loaded.

How can I filter the disabled products so I can remove the piece of code that loading each one to check if its disabled(!!!)

Comment: As horrible as expected. "Get all configurable products for the carousel" is not a joke, this code loads ALL configurable products (only filters disabled products, l.6, but no limit) with ALL their attributes (l.4) in memory. Then for each of them, it loads all simple products (l.18), and then loads each of them a second time (l.22)

Comment: the check for disabled products is actually redundant because this has already been filtered in the collection, i.e. with MySQL

Comment: This is a horrible peace of code. What is it even doing in a `.phtml` file? *smh

Comment: Some tips for efficient product collection loading that might help you: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/78497/243

Comment: Thanks, will try to "improve" (FIX?) this horrible code,
When I took the mission I excepted some caching missing not terrible code :)

Thanks alot guys.

Comment: Ok, I'm a bit lost. I know what data I want to get (all the configurable, plus one of their child so i can get image of each one)

Whats the best practice? I read your post (@fschmengler), but it seems to ask for only the right attributes (which i changed to)

Anyway to save me and show me some sample code of getting the same data this terrible code is getting but using best practices and not over-killing it?

Comment: I guess that qualifies for a separate question

Comment: You are right. just posted a new one :)